# Do I need to add the option to disable cookies or is just informational popup sufficient?

Tags: internet

recently I stumbled upon an EU law about cookies. It is quite unclear to me. I understand that all sites that use cookies has to have some kind of informational popup to tell the users that they use them. What is unclear to me is if it is sufficient to tell the user something like " If you are using this site you are agreeing with our cookies policy" or if it is required to have user give specific permission before any cookies (or any data to localstorage, sessionstorage, etc.) will be saved?

Thanks for the anwser!